# Transformation needed for placing cartesian coordinate rectangle on map using geographical coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, geojson, geometry, cartesian

I have come across a requirement to convert rectangle image with specific width and height to geographical coordinates so that it can be placed on map.  I have all the four geographical vertices for which the rectangle need to be placed. Assume [0,0] is mapped with North East position. Added a reference image

How can I transform the cartesian image to geographical coordinates, so that for a specific x,y coordinate I should be able to convert and mark on the map.
I require to write a script for the conversion, cannot use any tool.
[image: Final transformation]

Comment: Is the display really in Web Mercator? But you'll need to pass it lat/lon coordinates?